# hide/show a toggle in root.plist

Tags: ios, swift, featuretoggle, root.plist

I want to add a toggle in Root.plist of settings bundle for a feature. I want to hide the toggle on production and show it on the development build since the feature is not complete. I have added the toggle and checked the condition in the didfinishlaunching method using the debug and release check. But the toggle is still showing up on both builds. The condition check is only preventing the functioning of the toggle but is not hiding the toggle completely.ANY HELP would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't shown any code related to the problem. It's impossible to know why the toggle is or isn't displaying without seeing how you're doing that in your code. Try to include a [mre].

Comment: Didn't you post the same topic a few hours ago?